# Current in Inductor and Capacitor with DC voltage source?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, oscillators, inductance

A DC source in series with pure Inductor and pure Capacitor no Resistance. How the current will flow in this circuit? What I just know is that in the beginning Inductor will behave as an open circuit but then will allow the current to pass through it

[image]

to charge the capacitor. When the charge on capacitor will be equal to the charge in battery then the current will stop flowing as now both capacitor and battery are at equal and opposite potential. What I do not understand is that what will happen after that. Will current stop forever? The simulation shows that there is a continues flow of charge in one and then in other direction forever. How is this possible. What in this circuit will make the current to flow in one and then other direction forever?

Comment: What simulation?

Comment: simulation of the current through this circuit

Comment: Simply saying "simulation of the circuit" is about as vague as saying "a book" to the question "What are you reading." I had assumed as much given the definition of the word *simulation*. Things that might be useful in giving a proper response include: what software is it? what assumptions does that software make? is it reproducible in other software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking about inductors on a conceptual level, the thing to remember is that they oppose change in current.  In other words, if the current, $i$, is dropping, they provide voltage in the direction of that current; if $i$ is increasing, they provide voltage in the other direction (this can be very loosely thought of as resembling "inertia" in the circuit). Formally,

$$
v_i = L\frac{di}{dt}
$$

When the circuit is initially connected, or the voltage source turned on, the current wants to start immediately (and without a resistor, it wants to jump to an infinite current).  But this is impossible, because an instantaneous change in current would cause $v_i$ to be infinite, which is ludicrous, and which would necessarily oppose the current causing it (we would need some calculus and differential equations to handle this all properly, but your question was conceptual, so I'm keeping my response on that level.)  Instead we see a slow increase in the current, which charges the capacitor.

As long as the current is increasing, the inductor opposes it, preventing it from charging the capacitor at full speed.  As the capacitor charges, however, the current begins to drop.  Now the inductor switches roles, and begins to "prop up" the dropping current.  The result is that the capacitor experiences a voltage greater than the DC source.  This causes it to "overcharge", i.e. it takes on more charge than the DC source alone could give it. This is unsustainable; as the rate at which the current is dropping necessarily slows, the inductor is unable to provide the extra voltage, and the current reverses direction, flowing against the voltage of the DC source.

At this point the process basically starts all over again, although the point where the current reverses direction will be different, because we're now starting off with a current going against the DC source, as opposed to with it.

A very good analogy to this problem is a weight on a vertical spring; when let go from any point other than its equilibrium, it while oscillate forever.  In this analogy, the charge on the capacitor is the position of the spring--it stores energy, and exerts a force (or a voltage) on the system as it tries to release that energy.  The current is then the motion of the weight (i.e. the derivative of the charge, or of the position) and the inductor is the inertia of the object, which resists change to motion (or to current).  The DC source, then, is gravity: providing a constant force, or voltage, trying to move the system in one direction.

Just like the mass on the spring, the current, and charge of the capacitor, will oscillate eternally.

For a reasonably good mathematical explanation, see [the wikipedia page on LC circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).  It will be difficult to follow if you haven't studied differential equations, and unfortunately it only covers the math fully for LC circuits without a voltage source.

Comment: so when a capacitor is fully charged for the first time and flow of charge is stopped then immediately inductor reverses its polarity because it wants the current to go on that way in which it was already flowing so the capacitor now experience two batteries (one voltage source and other from reversal in the direction of polarity of inductor.) this will charger the capacitor more until it become equal and opposite to the combined polarity of voltage source and inductor. now the capacitor has charge more than the battery so the charge will flow in reverse direction now to charge the battery.

Comment: am i right @user1816730

Comment: That's the basic idea.  It's important to remember that when an inductor is involved, nothing happens "immediately", because it's impossible for the current through an inductor to change instantly.  But it sounds like you've got the basic idea.

I would try looking at the problem without the battery, starting with a charged capacitor; the math is much easier (it's exactly the same as the simple harmonic oscillator), and it gives you the oscillating result, which is the most important thing.

Comment: yes solution of second order differential equation will tell us the current flow in the circuit but i was looking for theoretical explaination of the circuit and you helped me alot in getting that.

Comment: Good--glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If the source is always connected,what you said is true,the capacitor won't conduct current unless it experiences dielectric breakdown at very high PD across it, when it will behave like a conductor. This normally does not happen. If the source is removed after the inductor is magnetically saturated, and the circuit is a closed loop,there will be LC oscillations.